# I want to change the hover color to red. Wrote a topic for this element does not respond, how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the hover color to red. Wrote a topic for this element does not respond, how to fix it? it turns out it goes dark by default, I want to change it to another color, for example, red, but it doesn't work
[image]

```
  MuiOutlinedInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& $notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "#ff0000",
          },
          "&:hover $notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "#ff0000",
          },
          "&$focused $notchedOutline": {
            borderWidth: 0,
          },
        },
      },
    },


import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";

const Search = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <OutlinedInput />
    </>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "#ff0000"
          },
          "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "#ff0000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-cherry-yol9c2?file=/src/App.js:99-451)

`$notchedOutline` doesn't work for me.

Comment: can you show how it looks like in full more expanded form?

Comment: where to enter the properties, how they look

Comment: @Виктория https://codesandbox.io/s/old-cherry-yol9c2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @user4980215 do you need to use !important here? You shouldn't need to with MUI.

Comment: @Nathan You are right. Better to use `.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline`. I will update the answer.